# How to mock a non existent file open

Tags: unit-testing, pytest

Consider the following code

```
def myFunc():
    with open('/tmp/file.json', 'r') as f:
         json_data = json.load(f)
    return
```

How to write a test case for this function?
Please Note that '/tmp/file.json' will not be present in the server which runs the UnitTest

Comment: What do you want to test about myFunc?

Comment: I wanted to test if json_data loads the contents of file.json. But the place where the pytest runs does not have /tmp/file.json file

Comment: So you would be testing Python's own built in file operation methods. Maybe broaden your example as I feel the code sample you have posted isn't really capturing the idea in your head.

Answer (score 0):

You have picked an unfortunate piece of code to start trying out unit-testing: A function like `myFunc` is typically not unit-tested: On the contrary, such functions are often created to separate interactions with the environment from the "rest of the code", just to make that "rest of the code" easier unit-testable.  Then, when the "rest of the code" is tested, `myFunc` can be replaced by a mock, such that different file contents or missing files can be simulated.

For testing functions like `myFunc`, integration testing (which is quite different from unit-testing) is a better suited testing approach.

Answer (score 0):

One option to this case would be, changing little bit your code

content of file.py

```
TMP_FILE = '/tmp/file.json'
def my_func(file=TMP_FILE):
    with open(TMP_FILE, 'r') as f:
         json_data = json.load(f)
return
```

And in your test_file.py

```
TMP_FILE = 'tmp_file.py'

@pytest.fixture
def tmp_file():
    with open(TMP_FILE, 'w') as file:
        file.write('sample content')
    yield TMP_FILE
    os.remove(TMP_FILE)

def test_my_func(tmp_file):
   my_func(tmp_file)
```

This is the way to use a file, but to make a real test maybe you should think in some kind of assert with a json schema:
file.py

```
TMP_FILE = '/tmp/file.json'
def my_func(file=TMP_FILE):
    with open(TMP_FILE, 'r') as f:
         json_data = json.load(f)
    return validate(instance=json_data, schema=schema)
```

test_file.py

```
def test_my_func():
   assert my_func(TMP_FILE)
```

More or less

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit of an overkill, but the package [pyfakefs](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs/) takes care of mocking virtual files. In the docs, there is this [example](http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/usage.html#patch-using-fake-filesystem-unittest-patcher):

```py
from pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest import Patcher

with Patcher() as patcher:
    # access the fake_filesystem object via patcher.fs
    patcher.fs.create_file('/foo/bar', contents='test')

    # the following code works on the fake filesystem
    with open('/foo/bar') as f:
        contents = f.read()
```

This allows you to mock a file with custom contents.

In your case, something like this can work:

```py
from pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest import TestCase

class ExampleTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.setUpPyfakefs()

    def test_create_file(self):
        file_path = '/tmp/file.json'
        test_content = '{"foo": "bar"}'
        self.assertFalse(os.path.exists(file_path))
        self.fs.create_file(file_path, contents=test_content)
        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(file_path))
        myFunc() # Test behavior after this
```